# What is changelog.Debian.gz file during packaging?

Tags: apt, compiling, packaging, c++

while packaging I encountered following error

```
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package `remotedevicecontroller' in `../remotedevicecontroller_1.0-1_i386.deb'.
 dpkg-source -b remotedevicecontroller-1.0
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: error: unwanted binary file: debian/remotedevicecontroller/usr/share/doc/remotedevicecontroller/changelog.Debian.gz
dpkg-source: error: detected 1 unwanted binary file (add it in debian/source/include-binaries to allow its inclusion).
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b remotedevicecontroller-1.0 gave error exit status 29
```

why is the file being created by debian-helper and why is it again asking to include it in some other directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the build wasn't clean, or you included more options that weren't by default. The changelog.Debian.gz is a gzip compressed list of the change made to the source package done by the Debian maintainer. You can either delete/prevent the generation of the file, or add the path to `debian/source/include-binaries`:

```
$ cat debian/source/include-binaries
[...]
/usr/share/doc/remotedevicecontroller/changelog.Debian.gz
[...]
```

Comment: adding it overcame the error but the process slumped into other. what do you mean by "build wasn't clean"? `dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to remotedevicecontroller: binary file contents changed`

Comment: how to make a clean build? thanq..

Comment: i added all the files it asked me to do into `debian/source/include-binaries` and finally it threw me `dpkg-source: error: aborting due to unexpected upstream changes, see /tmp/remotedevicecontroller_1.0-1.diff.mFPOPi`

Comment: To make a clean build I recommend you to delete your building directory and unpack it again. For the other error, you will need to ask another question and include the contents of `/tmp/remotedevicecontroller_1.0-1.diff.mFPOPi` and a link about this question explaining what are you trying to do.

Comment: actually I've written the code in netbeans, so I am creating the tarball of the project folder and place it in the project folder location. I am doing `make clean` which is generated by IDE. Isn't it enough to clean the build? anyway I made a copy of project before experimenting.

Comment: If you want to make patch to the project I recommend you to use `quilt` (the one debian uses) or I_don't_remember_what_ubuntu_uses_for_patch