# How to fix apt-get "unmet dependecies" errors?

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to install anything with `apt-get`, I get error messages:

```
apt-get install abinit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng12-0 : Breaks: libpng12-0:i386 (!= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 libpng12-0:i386 : Breaks: libpng12-0 (!= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I fix this?  If I try the suggested `apt-get -f install` command, it complains:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.2.54-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpng12-0:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What would a smart person do?

Comment: My read of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213976/should-i-mark-as-duplicate-if-the-question-is-answered-elsewhere-but-its-not-t is that while the answers to that question and this one do seem likely to be the same, the questions are different enough that this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line seems significant:

`trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz'`

An older post ([What is changelog.Debian.gz file during packaging?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337419/what-is-changelog-debian-gz-file-during-packaging)) suggests that you can safely remove `changelog.Debian.gz` (and you can certainly back it up with `sudo cp /usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/changelog.Debian.gz ~/Desktop/changelog.Debian.gz`)

So in this case I would start by removing the changelog, and then updating.

Usually, when I'm getting errors with `apt` or `apt-get` I also just run `sudo apt-get clean` to do some basic tidying.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the changelog.Debian file and that solved the problem for me.  Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Reconfigure the package database with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Then try again. If this still doesn't work, try removing libpng.

Comment: It's not likely a configuration issue. Overwrite errors usually occur when users try to install similarly-named packages from different sources.

Comment: @user535733 > If this still doesn't work, try removing libpng.